# Using Scanner to Search Key in Hash Map

Tags: java, hashmap, java.util.scanner

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class MyMap {
    public static void main (String[] args) {

        Map<String, Car> cars = new HashMap<> ();
        cars.put ("ID1", new Car("Dave", "LT12 DDS"));
        cars.put ("ID2", new Car("Steve", "GB14 HHG"));
        cars.put ("ID3", new Car("Molly", "LT18 SDF"));


        System.out.println ("Car with ID1 is " + cars.get ("ID1"));



    }
}
```

I can get the details from the map without using the scanner class.
I would like to have a user input the ID and get the results from the HashMap

```
class Car {
    public Car (String name, String barcode) {
        this.name = name;
        this.barcode = barcode;
    }

    public String toString () {
        return "Car: " + name + " (" + barcode + ")";
    }

    public final String name;
    public final String barcode;
}
```

This works until i try to add the scanner part. I want the user to enter the ID and then the results to be retrieved from the Hash Map

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MyMap {
    public static void main (String[] args) {

        Map<String, Car> cars = new HashMap<> ();
        cars.put ("ID1", new Car("Dave", "LT12 DDS"));
        cars.put ("ID2", new Car("Steve", "GB14 HHG"));
        cars.put ("ID3", new Car("Molly", "LT18 SDF"));

        Scanner ab=new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter ID: ");
        int id=ab.nextInt();




          //user input should get details from HashMap??
        System.out.println ("Car with ID1 is " + cars.get (int id));

        //System.out.println ("Car with ID1 is " + cars.get ("ID1"));

    }
}


//the Car class

class Car {
    public Car (String name, String barcode) {
        this.name = name;
        this.barcode = barcode;
    }
```

I am struggling with getting the Hash Map to get the details when the user input supplies the ID number.

Comment: You have a map with `String` keys. Why would you expect the `get` method to do anything when using a `int` as argument? You need to use a `String`. Maybe something like: `cars.get("ID" + id)`.

Comment: Thanks I did not see that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your map `cars` is of type `Map<String, Car>`.
So to get a car from the map you need to call `cars.get` with a `String` as argument.

Instead of calling `ab.nextInt()` use `ab.nextLine()`. This will return the complete inputed line as `String`, which you can use as key for your map.

```
Map<String, Car> cars = new HashMap<> ();                   
cars.put ("ID1", new Car("Dave", "LT12 DDS"));             
cars.put ("ID2", new Car("Steve", "GB14 HHG"));
cars.put ("ID3", new Car("Molly", "LT18 SDF"));

Scanner ab=new Scanner(System.in);  

System.out.println("Enter ID: ");  
String inputedID = ab.nextLine();

System.out.println("Car with " + inputedId + " is " + cars.get(inputedId));
```

To pretty print your car override the `toString` method of `Car.class` like in shahaf's answer:

> `@Override
>   public String toString() {
>       return this.name + "[" + this.barcode + "]";
>   }`

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyMap {

    enter code here
        public static void main (String[] args) {

            Map<String, Car> cars = new HashMap<>();
            cars.put ("ID1", new Car("Dave", "LT12 DDS"));
            cars.put ("ID2", new Car("Steve", "GB14 HHG"));
            cars.put ("ID3", new Car("Molly", "LT18 SDF"));

            Scanner ab=new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("Enter ID: ");
            String id=ab.next();

            System.out.println ("Car with ID1 is " + cars.get (id));



        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes I should have noticed